# How to block bots in cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare

How to block all bots except Google bot. I am using Cloudflare but I am confused, how to do.

I want all bots except these face Cloudflare JS Challenge. Screenshot will be helpful. And also, do the users/visitors will face JS Challenge.

Comment: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-block-all-bots-except-google/101905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is **no easy way to block all bots** using Cloudflare (I can say that after a lot of research and many useless chats with their support).

At the moment Cloudflare can only:

- **block malicious bots** that perform attacks detected by **WAF rules** (e.g. SQL injections)
- **block malicious bots** that performed attacks or sent spam in the past (based on their **IP reputation**)
- **block malicious bots** that are part of a **DDoS** attack
- **rate limit bots and users** using the rate limiting feature
- **detect and whitelist safe / known bots** (*cf.client.bot*) like Google

There is also an interesting feature called **Bot Management**, which is available **only for Enterprise customers** ($2k/mo). That feature provides a **bot score**, based on **the actual behavior of the client** (similarly to reCAPTCHA v3). The score (and other related features) should make it easier to block most bots at firewall level.